# Rindler Coordinate Transformation (Cylindrical Coordinates)

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus

How might one go about transforming from cylindrical flat space:
$$ds^2=-dt^2+d\rho^2+dz^2+\rho^2d\phi^2,$$
to Rindler space represented by:
$$ds^2=-\rho^2dt^2+d\rho^2+dz^2+d\phi^2?$$
The normal Minkowski to standard Rindler space i.e.
$$ds^2=-dt^2+dx^2+dy^2+dz^2 \rightarrow ds^2=-x^2dt^2+dx^2+dy^2+dz^2,$$
is easy and given everywhere but cylindrical space has been driving my nuts.

Comment: Suggestion: cylindrical $\to$ cartesian $\to$ Rindler. It somewhat confuses the issue using the same symbols for coordinates in different parametrizations.

Comment: @A.V.S. I think I left out a key point that standard Minkowski to standard Rindler is easy, not Minkowski to the cylindrical version. The question has been edited. If the edit wasn't needed, and I misunderstood your suggestion, then I can tell you that I have tried that and haven't figure it out either.

Comment: Can you go from cylindrical to Minkowski? If so, you've answered your own question.